# App.js file uncessary in New Version of React Router v6.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I don't understand the purpose of an App.js file in the new react router v6.4

With this new code in my App.js file my routes look like this

App.js code

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/reports",
        element: <Reports />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
                    createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

Then in my index.js file it has the default code like this

index.js code

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

The problem now is my browser says "export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App' (module has no exports)" and I don't know how you would convert my App.js code to even export default App since I never even used the function App() {} method

If I simply just delete the App.js file and copy all my code into my index.js file, then everything works like normal.

So basically just having one single index.js file with this code below works completely fine

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/reports",
        element: <Reports />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
                    createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

However, once I try to app an App.js file and import it, I get an error because it says no exports yet I don't see where I would even export it since I never created the App function

Why does CRA still include both the app.js and index.js since the new React Router v6.4 doesn't seem to need it?

Comment: It was never explicitly needed. `App.js` is just a file. Are you asking why when not exporting `App` for import into `index.js` why there was an error? Could you edit your post to include more complete code as part of your [mcve] so it is exactly clear to readers here what it is doing?

Comment: I don't understand how to export my App.js with the new react router v6.4 since I didn't have to create the typical function App () { ...routes } like in previous versions

Comment: the code above is literally the code in my files, minus the import react from react etc statements. The main problem is how do I remove the default app export error that shows because I don't have any `export default app` in my App.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does CRA still include both the app.js and index.js since the new
> React Router v6.4 doesn't seem to need it?

CRA creates a default app that uses both `index.js` and base `App.js` files since this is a standard convention. Using an `App.js` was never a requirement though, and certainly nothing any 3rd-party library like `react-router-dom` would be opinionated about nor be able to control.

You are not creating and exporting an `App` component in the first example, this is why attempting to import `App` failed. In fact, the `App.js` file was directly rendering to the DOM with the following:

```
createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
```

You can still declare and export an `App` component if you like.

Example:

App.js

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <Products />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "/reports",
        element: <Reports />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const App = () => <RouterProvider router={router} />;

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: do I still need to include ` <BrowserRouter>` wrapped around the App component in the index.js file? or what's the difference with wrapping with `<Strictmode>`?

Comment: @jrjay1 No, since you created the browser router with `createBrowserRouter` in `App.js`. Using the [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) component is also another standard convention. It helps you write better code by doing extra debugging "things" in non-production builds of your app, i.e. it helps expose logical errors and bugs in your code. It's not a requirement, but it's certainly ***strongly*** recommended.

Comment: ah I see, so regardless if I just simply kept all my code in my index.js and didn't do any export default App, then it would still be the same thing as the code you wrote above? or is adding the new index.js file with strictmode change the outcome behind the scenes?

Comment: @jrjay1 Yeah, basically. You can import all the UI components into `App.js` and compose the app there, export + import into `index.js`, and render to the DOM... ***or*** import all the UI components into `index.js`, compose the app JSX there, and render to the DOM. And just about anything else that ultimately gets the app's JSX code to the `root.render` function to render it to the DOM.